# What does git+ssh mean in an npm repo path like git+ssh://git@github.com/xxx.git

Tags: git, github, npm, package.json

I saw an npm repo that is referred to in package.json as `git+ssh://git@github.com/xxx.git`. I know this is ssh protocol, but I don't know what git+ssh does as when cloning the repo, I only use `git@github.com/xxx.git`. I googled around but cannot hit any result on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When hosting npm packages via git, npm also needs to know which transfer protocol to use to transfer the package files from the repo to the client. For this the following options exist: ssh, https, http, file (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

The creators of npm decided to place this information in the protocol name separating the information with a `+` symbol so it becomes more schematic. So when `npm install` iterates over your dependencies and sees a dependency with `git+ssh` it knows that it will connect to the repo via `ssh` and then use your local `git` binaries to checkout the project files locally.

I guess they could have also named the protocol `gitwithssh` as in `gitwithssh://git@github.com/xxx.git` but `git+ssh` looks just more concise and logically separated, thus easier to parse via a regex.

Here is the part in the npm source code that is actually responsible for splitting the protocol information into the `type` (= `git`) and the actual protocol (e.g. `ssh`): https://github.com/npm/npm-package-arg/blob/v7.0.0/npa.js#L221

> I only use git@github.com/xxx.git.

You cannot use this format to register a package as dependency with npm. Try executing `npm i git@github.com/xxx.git` – it won't work. This format can only be used e.g. via `git clone`.

However, you can use this format when prefixing it with the ssh protocol: `ssh://git@github.com/xxx.git`. This is actually the "normalized" form of "git+ssh" which is used by npm behind the curtains (see also how https://github.com/npm/normalize-git-url transforms your `git+ssh://...` into `ssh://git@...`).

Comment: As I realized my question is connected to npm, I found  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install where it describes the protocols that can be used to install packages from git remote URLs. Hope it could help.

Answer (score 2):

From an NPM perspective this similar to any other remote setup.  Many dependency managers support using Git over SSH.  Under the hood, this drives Git to connect over SSH.  The end result is NPM clones the repository and installs it into your `node_modules` directory.

When Git communicates with a remote repository it launches one of two programs using SSH: either `git-upload-pack` or `git-receive-pack`.  The repository is given as an option to these commands.  SSH is used a tunneling mechanism to issue commands to these remote programs using the  `pkt-line` protocol.  More details about the protocol can be found in the [Git source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt#L103).